# Cassandra BoundStatement, how insert duration type?

Tags: cassandra

I create a [Duration Column](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql//cql/cql_reference/upsertDates.html) for Cassandra table.

Using SQL we can provide values for a duration without quotes.

```
INSERT INTO cycling.race_times (
  finish_time,
  race_name, cyclist_name, race_date
) VALUES (
  1h4m48s20ms,
  '17th Santos Tour Down Under', 'Rohan DENNIS', '2017-04-14'
);
```

**But if I use a BoundStatement, how can pass the parameter?**

```
boundStatement.setDate(..)
boundStatement.setTime(..)
boundStatement.setTimestamp(..)
etc...
```

But, we haven't a `bound.setObject` like JDBC

using: `Apache Cassandra 3.11.1`, `JDK 1.8` and `cassandra-driver-core:3.8.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generic form of the `set` function, like this:

```java
boundStatement.set(name_or_index, Duration.from("duration_value"), Duration.class);
```

you can also use `Duration.newInstance` to create Duration object if you have it expressed as months/days/nanoseconds

Comment: Thanks works. I have to write a Converter between java.time.Duration and com.datastax.driver.core.Duration, otherwise CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [duration <-> java.time.Duration] is launched.

Comment: The optional codecs could contain ready to use implementation.  Look into docs for section in custom codecs

Comment: the new Java driver has a note that no of the Java 8 time types can represent duration accurately: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.4/manual/core/temporal_types/ - I'm not 100% sure why this is a case...

Comment: yes, there are many nuances in time concepts...`CQL type duration` represents a period in **months**, **days** and **nanoseconds** while `java.time.Duration` amount of time in terms of **seconds** and **nanoseconds**

[We deliberately avoided java.time.Period, because it does not contain a nanoseconds part as CqlDuration does; and avoided java.time.Duration, because it represents an time-based amount, regardless of the calendar, whereas CqlDuration manipulates conceptual days and months instead](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.4/manual/core/temporal_types/#duration)